# How do I open downloaded ubuntu file?

Tags: software-installation

When I try to open ubuntu downloaded file, Windows asks for name of program that created the file.  What is the answer?

Comment: Please edit the question and add more information on the file type or extension.

Comment: Are you trying to open the `.iso` file?

Comment: Ditch windows forever

Answer (score 1):

Download [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/). You can use it to burn the cd image file onto a disk and then run (just reboot your computer with the disk inside) it to install Ubuntu